# Current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know that there are other questions with the exact title as the one I posted but each of them are very specific to the query or procedure they are referencing.

I manage a Blackboard Learn system here for a college and have direct database access. In short there is a stored procedure that is causing system headaches. Sometimes when changes to the system get committed errors are thrown into logs in the back end, identifying a stored procedure known as `bbgs_cc_setStmtStatus` and erroring out with `The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.`

Here is the code for the SP, however, I did not write it, as it is a stock piece of "equipment" installed by Blackboard when it populates and creates the tables for the application.

```
USE [BBLEARN]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[bbgs_cc_setStmtStatus]    Script Date: 09/27/2013 09:19:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE              [dbo].[bbgs_cc_setStmtStatus](
   @registryKey   nvarchar(255),
   @registryVal   nvarchar(255),
   @registryDesc  varchar(255),
   @overwrite     BIT
) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @message varchar(200);

  IF (0 < (SELECT count(*) FROM bbgs_cc_stmt_status WHERE registry_key = @registryKey) ) BEGIN
    IF( @overwrite=1 ) BEGIN
      UPDATE bbgs_cc_stmt_status SET
        registry_value = @registryVal,
        description    = @registryDesc,
        dtmodified     = getDate()
      WHERE registry_key = @registryKey;
    END
  END
  ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bbgs_cc_stmt_status
        (registry_key, registry_value, description) VALUES
        (@registryKey, @registryVal, @registryDesc);
  END

  SET @message = 'bbgs_cc_setStmtStatus: Saved registry key [' + @registryKey + '] as status [' + @registryVal + '].';
  EXEC dbo.bbgs_cc_log @message, 'INFORMATIONAL';

END
```

I'm not expecting Blackboard specific support, but I want to know if there is anything I can check as far as SQL Server 2008 is concerned to see if there is a system setting causing this. I do have a ticket open with Blackboard but have not heard anything yet.

Here are some things I have checked:

tempdb system database:

I made the templog have an initial size of 100MB and have it auto grow by 100MB, unrestricted to see if this was causing the issue. It didn't seem to help. Our actual tempdb starts at 4GB and auto grows by a gig each time it needs it. Is it normal for the space available in the tempdb to be 95-985 of the actual size of the tempdb? For example, right now tempdb has a size of 12388.00 MB and the space available is 12286.37MB.

Also, the log file for the main `BBLEARN` table had stopped growing because it reached its maximum auto grwoth. I set its initial size to 3GB to increase its size.

Comment: That error can be generated by bbgs_cc_log storage procedure. Can you show bbgs_cc_log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of potential errors that could be preventing the commit but without knowing more about the structure these are just guesses:

1. The update clause in the nested if is trying to update a column (or set of columns) that must be unique. Because the check only verifies that at least one item exists but does not limit that check to making sure only one item exists

   ```
   IF (0 < (SELECT ...) ) BEGIN
   ```

   vs.

   ```
   IF (1 = (SELECT ...) ) BEGIN
   ```

   you could be inserting non-unique values into rows that must be unique. Check to make sure there are no constraints on the attributes the update runs on (specifically look for primary key, identity, and unique constraints). Likelyhood of this being the issue: Low but non-zero.
2. The application is not passing values to all of the parameters causing the @message string to null out and thus causing the logging method to error as it tries to add a null string. Remember that in SQL anything + null = null so, while you're fine to insert and update values to null you can't log nulls in the manner the code you provided does. Rather, to account for nulls, you should change the setter for the message variable to the following:

   ```
   SET @message = 'bbgs_cc_setStmtStatus: Saved registry key [' + COALESCE(@registryKey, '') + '] as status [' + COALESCE(@registryVal,'') + '].';
   ```

   This is far more likely to be your problem based on the reported error but again, without the app code (which might be preventing null parameters from being passed) there isn't any way to know.

Also, I would note that instead of doing a

```
IF (0 < (SELECT count(*) ...) ) BEGIN
```

I would use

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...) ) BEGIN
```

because it is more efficient. You don't have to return every row of the sub-query because the execution plan will run the FROM statement first and see that rows exist rather than having to actually evaluate the select, count those rows, and then compare that with 0.

Start with those suggestions and, if you can come back with more information, I can help you troubleshoot more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a MERGE statement : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

I think it will be more efficient.

Answer (score -4):

1. Launch SSMS
2. Navigate to the database name
3. Right click on the database name and choose Properties > Options
4. Change "Delayed Durability" to Allowed
5. Click OK

Comment: This is terrible advice. If anyone is tempted to do this, contact me... I'll try to "talk you off the ledge"